# Acrescentar um zero quando houver apenas 1 decimal

Tags: php, number-format

Boas pessoal, eu possuo um sistema para emissão de nota fiscal eletronica, existe uma regra do governo onde os valores das duplicatas(parcelas) devem possuir exatas 2 casas decimais. Eu utilizo o number_format para declarar que mostre apenas duas casas decimais, porém quando o numero for um decimal inteiro ele não mostra um zero, exemplo:

Parcela 1 : R$ 140,11
Parcela 2: R$ 140,10

O que acontece é que quando mostra a parcela 2 ele me exibe R$ 140,1 , ou seja, come um zero, alguem saberia me informar como acrescento esse zero quando acontecer esse caso?

Utilizo assim para mostrar duas casas decimais:

```
number_format($calcula_duplicata, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Tem certeza? [Aqui retornou 140.10 mesmo...](https://ideone.com/IyGbTB)

Comment: Fiz no meu localhost o seu exato código e o retorno foi `140.10`

Comment: Sim, ja percebi isso, o problema é que no que gera o xml ele come esse zero

Comment: Eu queria algo que identificasse a quantia de casas decimais que tem e se for igual a 1 acrescentar um zero

Comment: Mas é exatamente o mesmo código? Consegue elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: Mas esse código php que você colocou na pergunta já faz isso Nicholas.